# I made an instance of CipherSpi class for a project and I get "JCE cannot authenticate the provider"

Tags: java, securityexception

I'm making a project, and in the project it's part of our work to remake a cipher algorithm and others and then to use them using the JCA (java criptographic architecture) rules.

I have made a provider that provides multiple classes. All seems to be working well until I try to use getInstance().
I made, among others, a DH (extends KeyAgreementSpi) class for KeyAgreement different usages

```
KeyAgreement dh = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH", myProvider);
```

I get:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider Ts001Proj1Provider
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:114)
at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:263)
at fcul.ts001.proj1.SecuredStream.(SecuredStream.java:194)
at fcul.ts001.proj1.SecureStreamTest.run(SecureStreamTest.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot verify jar:file:/*pathToProject*/proj/Main/bin/!/
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:406)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:161)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:187)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:110)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: *pathToProject*\proj\Main\bin (Access is denied)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:384)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: *pathToProject*\proj\Main\bin (Access is denied)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:214)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:144)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:153)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.(URLJarFile.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:98)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$2.run(JarVerifier.java:399)
... 11 more
```

The best part is that this code executed well:
`KeyPairGenerator dhKeyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH", myProvider);`

Why do I get it?

I'm working on win6.1 x64

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more to it than just implementing one class. You have to get your provider certified for a start. Why are you doing this?